# Simple Question about Interpretation of Poisson Distribution

Tags: intuition, poisson-distribution

So if you know for instance, an individual keeping track of the amount of mail they receive each day may notice that they receive an average number of 4 letters per day. Can the Poisson distribution tell you anything about the probability of N pieces of mail in, say, a 12-hour window, or is it only about to be used for the exact 24-hour window?

Comment: Given that letters are generally not  delivered from $8$ PM to $8$ AM, the size of the window will matter if a Poisson is to have a chance of fitting.

Comment: Suppose mails/e-mails come in at intensity $\lambda(t)$. Then the number of items received in $[t_1,t_2]$ is $Poisson(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\lambda(t)\,dt)$. This should accommodate varying intensity and time-frames.